# How to calculate the following Probability given the combination of discrete and continuous events? Is it even possible?

Tags: probability, statistics

This is a problem i came up with myself, but i don't even know how to start to solve it? So maybe somebody here knows or sees a way to approach it:

You are given a dice with $n \in \mathbb{N}$  sides $A_1,A_2...A_n$ each with the same chance to occur. Now if you hit even indicesed faces, you get a random amount of money $X\sim [0,2n ]$ and if you hit an odd faced one you get $X\sim [0,n]$ but additionally you are allowed to throw the dice again (if you want) under the condition that if you get an even indicessed face on the second throw, you lose all your money.

Assume that you hit an odd faced dice and have to decide whether to continue or not if your goal is to gain as much money as possible. Since the amount of money is continuous, but the throw of the dice is discrete, how would one compute any of this in the first place? is it even possible to compute anything?

What is the field of study called that allows me to calculate such things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to interpret your question, and your problem indeed has a Solution. If you can throw the die again any number of times as long as you get an odd number, then there is no maximum amount of money you can win, since you can always risk more in order to increase it.

Most of these kind of problems are approached by computing the expected value of a Random variable, which by the Law of Large numbers is the average value when you repeat the experiment infinitely many times, so the best choice is the one that makes you get a bigger expected value. In this case(I'll assume $n$ is even, you can work by your own the odd case after understanding this one), We can define $Y$ as the random variable defined by the total amount you earn if you throw the die again. And $N$ as the amount you get if you don't.

If you don't throw the die again you earn $X\sim[0,n]$, so $N=X$ and then $E(N)=E(X)=\frac{n}{2}$ (I'm assuming your notation means uniform distribution).

If you throw the die again You have two possible outcomes:

$\bullet$ You get an even number and lose everything, in this case the probability of that event is $1/2$.

$\bullet$ You get again an odd number and win a random amount of money given by $X\sim[0,n]$.

Here we can't express with a single formula the behavior of the variable $Y$. But if we denote by $A$ the event of getting an odd indicized face, you can describe the conditional distributions $Y|A=N+U$, ($N\sim[0,n]$ represents the money you already won and $U\sim[0,n]$ is independent from $N$ and represents the money you will get for the second roll) and $Y|A^c=0$
Now, we use another result which is called the Law of total expectation, which grants

$$E(Y)=E(Y|A)P(A)+E(Y|A^c)P(A^c)$$
So we have by linearity of $E$:
$$E(Y)=[E(N)+E(U)]\frac{1}{2}+0\times \frac{1}{2}=\frac{E(N)+E(U)}{2}=\frac{\frac{n}{2}+\frac{n}{2}}{2}.$$

So $E(Y)=\frac{n}{2} =E(N).$

It means in average you will win the same amount independently of your choice (The even numbered die should be different since the probability is not $\frac{1}{2}$.)

The difference here is given by the risk you're willing to take. That's quantified by another operator of random variables called Variance. The bigger the variance, the higher the risk and the rewards.

Also, the random variables which are part discrete and part continuous are called mixed random variables

Comment: thanks for the great answer !!!